# Верстка меню в одну линию в браузере

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, все работает хорошо, за исключением того, что при увеличении в браузере масштаба, пункты меню переходят на новую строку, а хотелось бы, чтобы все было на одной.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fixie.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #nav,
        #nav ul {
            background-color: #444;
            font: 11px/28px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #nav {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            height: 28px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #nav a {
            border-right: 1px solid #000;
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            padding: 0px 20px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 70px;
        }
        #nav li {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        #nav li:hover,
        #nav li.jshover {
            background-color: #333;
        }
        #nav a:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: #000;
        }
        #nav ul {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-bottom: 0px;
            border-top: 0px;
            display: none;
            left: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 28px;
            width: 108px;
        }
        #nav ul a {
            border: 1px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            width: 68px;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul,
        #nav li.jshover ul {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Афиша</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Европейская кухня</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Японская кухня</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Корейская кухня</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Фото</a>
        <li><a href="#">Музыка</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Правила</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Информация</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда таблицей.

Если религия не велит использовать тэг `<table>`, то применяйте display: table-cell к элементам списка.

И да: если display: table-cell, то float следует убрать ибо он автоматом назначает display: block, а это уже другое поведение.

Comment: Спасибо, но не мог бы ты по подробней? я в css не очень, больше php, просто встал вопрос реализации такого) помоги

Comment: Куда уж подробнее :)
Берём код:
        #nav li {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
Меняем на:
        #nav li {
            display: table-cell;
            position: relative;
        }

Comment: И вот ещё какой момент: не следует задавать высоту явно. Как раз при масштабировании должно быть понятно почему. Правильнее всего вообще убрать height: 28px;

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо, ты меня выручил )

Comment: теперь выпадающий список 
<li><a href="#">Европейская кухня</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Японская кухня</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Корейская кухня</a></li>
горизонтально а не вертикально. и еще видно только первую, два остальных залиты белым фоном

Comment: Просто прописываются нужные стили для #nav li ul li, и всё.
Скорее всего будет достаточно display: block им дать.

Comment: еще, хорошо бы добавить костыли для ие7

Comment: нет, не хорошо.
Вам знакомо такое выражение как graceful degradation? А знаком процент пользователей IE вообще и IE7 в частности? И скорость их исчезновения.

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена, все оставил так как было у меня, только весь список заключил в

```
#menu {
    clear: both;    
    margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 790px;   
}
 <div id ="menu">список</div>
```